# Forward phase / reverse phase LED dimmer switch inverted - house wiring messed up?

Tags: electrical, led

I have a Lutron Caseta dimmer (model PD-5NE) which is an ELV+ dimmer which should be great for LED bulbs.  Its default configuration is "reverse phase" which is for ELV, but in that mode, there are times where the bulbs flicker sporadically, especially when dim.

This was happening again, so just to see if it made a difference I changed it to forward phase (MLV) using the programming it supports.  This solved it and the switching back and forth a few times confirmed that is what did the trick.  I can now have them on super dim and they are very good.

Does this indicate there could be some incorrect wiring in the house or some other electrical problem (the terminology reverse-phase and forward-phase made me wonder)? There are other areas which have problems with some LED bulbs and dimmers too, like we have 3 ceiling fans with an issue where the light and fan will spontaneously shut off briefly.

EDIT: it appears that while the flickering is gone, there is still some fluctuation happening but it's much more smoothed out so there aren't the abrupt flickers.  Also, I'm virtually certain the bulbs are "dimmable" LED if that matters.

Comment: Yes, it's rather important that the bulbs be dimmable if you're going to run them on a dimmer. I'd pull bulbs and check them. If they don't explicitly say, then look up the manufacturer(s) & model number(s) online to see whether they're dimmable or not. If not, replace a few and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yes, powerline dimming tech is astoundingly primitive and hacked.  It was designed to barely work with incandescent bulbs, and was optimized for "cheap" even then. Getting it to work with LEDs is a hack on top of a hack. Honestly it's amazing it works  at all.

Comment: What make and model of LED bulbs are you using?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it happens on Juno WF6REGSWW590CRIMWM6 from Lowes as well as on EcoSmart BR30 (SKU 1001655218) from Home Depot. The ceiling fans where the lights and fan shut off spontaneously are model 2193789 from Costco.